# Jest how to mock a typescript class but alternate some method behavior in only 1 test and not modify mock in others

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a typescript class userInfo.ts:

```
export class UserInfo {
  public getName() {
    return "I am real name";
  }
}
```

I have a mocked class userInfo.ts in **mocks** folder:

```
export class UserInfo {
  public getName() {
    return "I am fake name";
  }
}
```

I have a client:

```
import { UserInfo } from "./userInfo";
export class Client {

  public functionToTest() {
    let validation = new UserInfo();
    return validation.getName();
  }

}
```

And finally I want to have TWO tests for this, in the first one I want to overwrite the getName mock only for this test, and in the second one I want to have the mocked class behavior so:

```
import { Client } from "./client";
import { UserInfo } from "./userInfo";

jest.mock("./userInfo");
const userInfoMocked = UserInfo as jest.MockedClass<typeof UserInfo>; // I tried with this but with no success

describe("Client", () => {

  it("should get Name", () => {
    let client = new Client();
    // UserInfo.prototype.getName = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    //   return "Something weird happened";
    // });
    userInfoMocked.prototype.getName = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      return "something weird happend";
    });

    // this is not working either
    // Property 'getName' does not exist on type 'MockedClass<typeof UserInfo>'.
    // userInfoMocked.getName = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    //   return "something weird happend";
    // });

    let text = client.functionToTest();
    expect(text).toBe('something weird happend'); 
    let text2 = client.functionToTest();
    expect(text2).toBe('I am fake name'); // I get undefined (I overwrote prototype!)
  });

  it('should get fake name now', () => {
    let client = new Client();
    let text3 = client.functionToTest();
    expect(text3).toBe('I am fake name'); // I get undefined

  });
});
```

I am suprised that such a common (I think) functionality is not achievable? How to succeed in this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Why don't you jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce on the second test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to this:
It occurred that when not using manual mock (thus having UserInfo.ts under mocks) it does not work at all, but when getting rid of that manual mock and left automock, I could do:

```
import { mocked } from "ts-jest";
import { Client } from "./secretsManagerWrapper";
import { UserInfo } from "./userInfo";

jest.mock("./userInfo");
const userInfoMocked = mocked(UserInfo, false);

describe("Client", () => {
  it.only("should get Name", () => {
    let client = new Client();

    userInfoMocked.mockImplementationOnce(function () {
      return {
        getName: () => {
          return "John Doe Second";
        },
      };
    });
```

and it worked !

I discovered also that when I do want to use manual mock (under **mocks** folder) I can use a Spy:

```
describe("Client", () => {
  it("should get Name", () => {
    let client = new Client();

    jest.spyOn(userInfoMocked.prototype, "getName").mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      return "John Doe Second";
    });

    let text = client.functionToTest();
    expect(text).toBe("John Doe Second");
    let text2 = client.functionToTest();
    expect(text2).toBe("I am fake name"); // I get what I want now
  });

  it("should get fake name now", () => {
    let client = new Client();
    let text3 = client.functionToTest();
    expect(text3).toBe("I am fake name"); // I get what I want now !
  });
});
```

And I can accomplish what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a default implementation to the mock:

```
import userInfo from "./userInfo"
jest.mock("./userInfo", () => ({
  getName: jest.fn(() => 'John Doe'),
}));
```

And each time you want to overwrite the implementation:

```
userInfo.getName.mockImplementation(() => jest.fn().mockReturnValue('another value'));
```

Comment: It does not work when I am overwriting:

Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type 'typeof UserInfo'

Comment: I've updated the overwrite example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use different mocks in different tests, don't use the **mocks** folder. Instead create the mocks you need for each test. [This](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks) describes the different types of mocking you can do. Based on your description I would use mockImplementation. eg in one test you could do

```
UserInfo.mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    getName: () => {
      return 'I am a real name'
    }
  }
}
```

And in another test:

```
UserInfo.mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    getName: () => {
      return 'I am a fake name'
    }
  }
}
```

All the methods boil down to the same thing so it's a question of picking the one that fits in best with the structure of your code and is easy to maintain.

Comment: The thing is that when importing a CLASS of UserInfo, I am not able to write UserInfo.mockImplemention(() => ...) due to
Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type 'typeof UserInfo'.